# Codeigniter 3 remove index.php not working and throws 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am stuck with removing `index.php`.

mod Rewrite is enabled in my apache, I have checked earlier

my url

```
http://localhost/projects/ci/admin
```

Here is my controller

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Admin Function";
    }
}
```

here is my .htaccess file, which I copied from Codeigniter user_guide

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

done everything to run it:

changed 
`$config['base_url'] = '';` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projects/ci/';`

changed `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';` and vice-versa

also `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`
with the help of stackoverflow solutions but failed to do so.

Comment: Provide your `routes` if available

Comment: You should have to do this, but does it work if you specify the routes? Also, what is the name of the controller file?

Comment: You should configure the server so that `localhost` points to the folder `/what/ever/projects/ci/`. Then use `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';

Comment: Just because mod rewrite is enabled doesn't mean you're allowed to use .htaccess files. You need to ensure that apache is configured to Allowoverride = all

Comment: did you reload apache?

Comment: http://localhost/projects/ci/index.php/admin is this working @syed

Comment: controller file name is admin.php

Comment: localhost/projects/ci/index.php/admin yeah thats working

Comment: @Mukkhu Sukkhu Manush are you asking for routes.php file ??

Answer (score 0):

in .htaccess file
copy the below code and save it
and then try it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you save your controller as "Admin.php"or 'admin.php'. If you save it 'admin.php' then you have to save as "Admin.php".

Comment: i save it as admin.php ,

Comment: so you have to save as "Admin.php" not as "admin.php".

Comment: sure i will save it as "Admin.php" , and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my configuration on an application im developing (with CI)

In the file ../application/config/routes.php, line 53 on CI v3.1.6

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'MyDefaultController';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

As far as i know does not really matter if u remove index.php if all ur system files are allocated on the ../public_html folder on your server, if not, u should keep it and make the changes so CI "knows" where to find system, application and views files.

Also if u delete index.php and don't set the the default controller on routes.php, (sorry about my english here) CI will not find its "index page".

In short, check the default controller on routes.php
Hope it helps.